# How to install python module before installing addon?

Tags: python

I want to install the python module via `pip` before installing the addon.

The addon depends on the module which I want to install via `pip`

Comment: Note it's good practice to ask the user for permission before installing packages to their directories.

Comment: https://github.com/robertguetzkow/blender-python-examples/tree/master/add_ons/install_dependencies

Answer (score 1):

In the `__init__.py` inside `def register()` and before the modules imports. It does not import the modules, only installs. The function should be run every time the addon is activated as it adds required path `site.getusersitepackages()` where the installed modules are  located to `sys.path`. While installing Blender may appear frozen, but it actually downloads the modules. [Example](https://github.com/unwave/atool/blob/main/__init__.py).

Get `ensure_site_packages` code from here: https://gist.github.com/unwave/24f0ee4bfc9cc0af1bf35eda5d54d49f

```py
import site
ensure_site_packages.ensure_site_packages([
    ("PIL", "Pillow"),
    ("xxhash","xxhash"),
    ("bs4","beautifulsoup4"),
    ("pyperclip", "pyperclip"),
    ("cv2", "opencv-contrib-python"),
], site.getusersitepackages())
```

Can also use `ensure_site_packages.get_site_packages_directory()` which is `.\_deps\<python version>` relative to `ensure_site_packages.__file__`

Comment: It doesn't works

Comment: @Karan What is the error?

Comment: I tried and it's not installing any python package anywhere

Comment: What does it write to the console? Can you import the modules? The destination for the installed modules is site.getusersitepackages(), see what is the return value of it and look for the modules there.

Comment: I can't use `import <module>` inside blender python console, and I can't use `import <module>` in my addon files. It says <module> not found

Comment: Are the modules present in `site.getusersitepackages()`? Is `site.getusersitepackages()` in `sys.path` when you import?

Comment: Yeah,  it is available

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138712/discussion-between-unwave-and-karan).

Comment: This script uses the user's site-packages folder from the main python interpreter on the system, instead of the one used by Blender. Mixing these is a bad idea and could easily lead to problems. A better idea is to install the module to the addons directory to keep everything encapsulate. This location can be found with `bpy.utils.user_resource("SCRIPTS", path="addons/modules"`, and pip takes a `-t location` argument to install to the given location instead.

Comment: @Jasper A problem with just `addons/modules` is that it gets copied when you choose to transfer the previous Blender preferences to a newer Blender which can have a different Python version. So the distinction between `python37/site-packages` and `python311/site-packages` is lost. The `site.getusersitepackages()` was added to `sys.path` by default: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/commit/72c012ab4a3d2a7f7f59334f4912402338c82e3c

Comment: Some cases of the Blender's python version changing are covered by the logic in the PREFERENCES_OT_copy_prev operator.

https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/f33d7bb598ceae93af4e8eb1cee79e06a1b8950c/scripts/startup/bl_operators/userpref.py#L72-L158C28 
https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/f33d7bb598ceae93af4e8eb1cee79e06a1b8950c/scripts/startup/bl_operators/wm.py#L3193-L3201C4

But for example 2.93 would suggest to transfer the settings from 2.90 despite the fact that they use 3.9 and 3.7 python versions correspondingly.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the pip package is already included with blender 3.2. On the python console try the command import pip and then pip.[Tab autocomplete] to verify that it is able to navigate.

If you need you can install packages within your personal scripts folder that you can find (or change) via Edit :: Preferences :: File Paths :: Scripts:

[image]