# Is that possible to see the file details in real-time window using ImportHelper

Tags: python

I have created a file browser operator using *ImportHelper*. What I want is I want to see the selected file details in the same window as I have shown in the screenshot. And the properties should update as I select any other file.

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.io_utils import ImportHelper

class test_filebrowser(bpy.types.Operator, ImportHelper):
    bl_idname = 'test.file_browser'
    bl_label = 'Custom File Browser'

    filter_glob : bpy.props.StringProperty(default = '*.mp4',options={'HIDDEN'})
    resolution : bpy.props.IntVectorProperty(name='Resolution',size=2)

    def execute(self, context):
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text=f"Video Resolution: {self.resolution[0:2]}")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(test_filebrowser)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.register_class(test_filebrowser)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: You need to use `ffmpeg` module. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51342429/how-to-extract-metadata-of-video-files-using-python-3-7

Comment: It works fine with VS code but the Blender python console is not working with it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ulNE.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vW4T.png

Comment: Yes, you have to install `ffmpeg` module inside the blender python module. Read this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/272610/how-to-install-python-module-before-installing-addon

Comment: Blender has a separate python lib, so you have to install `ffmpeg` in that lib so that it can be used in blender's interactive python console or by your addon